# Understanding the domain of the triple integral for $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So, I am having trouble with the domain for the triple integral of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$, bounded by the paraboloid $x^2+y^2=2z$ and the $z=4$ plane

I am currently trying to project it on the XY axis, where, if I am not mistaken:

$0 \leq z\leq 4$

But...I don't see how I can "guess" how x and y are bounded, as far as I can see x and y are in function of each other

Is there something I am missing out?

Comment: Something is wrong here. $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ is not the equation of a paraboloid.

Comment: Sorry! Fixed, I had missed a $z$ at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reparametrize $f(x,y,z) = x^{2} + y^{2}$ using polar coordinates such that the paraboloid can be thought of as lots of discs (of max. radius $\sqrt{2z}$) which will vary from $0 \leq z \leq 4$, via:
$$
x = r \cos\theta,\qquad y = r \sin \theta,\qquad 0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2z},\quad 0 \leq \theta < 2\pi.
$$
With this reparametrisation, the volume element becomes $dx\, dy\, dz = r\, dr\,  d\theta\, dz$.

To try and use the limits of integration in the $xy$-coordinate system is superfluously messy, since as you anticipated the limit of $x$ would depend on $y$ and vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought about using polar coordinates once I had already focused on the XY plane